# PHP mysqli_result get current position

Tags: php, mysqli

```
mysqli_result->data_seek($offset)
```

will get you the row at that offset, but is there anyway to know what offset the result set is currently on?

Simple illustration....

```
 while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      //what offset is $result on now?
 }
```

While keeping tack of the above with a simple counter is easy, in more complex rewinding and fastforwarding sceanrios it becomes a pain. The
[implementations I've seen from years ago](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33914/14863/syntactic-sugar-for-mysqli-results-using-spl-iterators.html) wrote extension classes that ensured a manullay created counter was incremented no matter what the ->fetch_* (or data_seek) call was used. Is that still the only option?

**EDIT**

I've taken it upon myself to look into this by forking the mysqli extension [which is on github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/mysqli)
But I am a total beginner with C and PHP extension development. Here is my initial impression.

The mysqli_result_iterator.c defines the internal pointer as row_num

```
typedef struct {
    zend_object_iterator  intern;
    mysqli_object *result;
    zval current_row;
    my_longlong row_num; //THIS IS WHAT WE WANT TO EXPOSE!
} php_mysqli_result_iterator;
```

SO. In that I file it looks like I need to add a method...

```
 static long php_mysqli_result_iterator_row_num(zend_object_iterator *iter){
    php_mysqli_result_iterator *iterator = (php_mysqli_result_iterator*) iter;

    return iterator->row_num;
}
```

and add that function to the zend defs at the end of that file

```
zend_object_iterator_funcs php_mysqli_result_iterator_funcs = {
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_dtor,
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_valid,
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_current_data,
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_current_key,
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_move_forward,
    php_mysqli_result_iterator_rewind,

    //ADDING CURRENT ROW NUM RETURN
    php_msqli_result_iterator_row_num,
    NULL
};
```

Trying to chase down how the mysqli_result_iterator is used I find in the mysqli.c it is implemented like so...

```
    REGISTER_MYSQLI_CLASS_ENTRY("mysqli_result", mysqli_result_class_entry, mysqli_result_methods);
 ce = mysqli_result_class_entry;

//HERE IS THE ITERATOR
mysqli_result_class_entry->get_iterator = php_mysqli_result_get_iterator;
mysqli_result_class_entry->iterator_funcs.funcs = &php_mysqli_result_iterator_funcs;

zend_class_implements(mysqli_result_class_entry, 1, zend_ce_traversable);
```

However I cannot find anywhere where the iterator is ever interacted with to learn from.

tell me if I'm on the right track here... using fetch_all method definition from mysqli_nonapi.c which looks like this

```
 PHP_FUNCTION(mysqli_fetch_all)
{
MYSQL_RES   *result;
zval        *mysql_result;
zend_long       mode = MYSQLND_FETCH_NUM;

if (zend_parse_method_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), getThis(), "O|l", &mysql_result, mysqli_result_class_entry, &mode) == FAILURE) {
    return;
}
MYSQLI_FETCH_RESOURCE(result, MYSQL_RES *, mysql_result, "mysqli_result", MYSQLI_STATUS_VALID);

if (!mode || (mode & ~MYSQLND_FETCH_BOTH)) {
    php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Mode can be only MYSQLI_FETCH_NUM, "
                     "MYSQLI_FETCH_ASSOC or MYSQLI_FETCH_BOTH");
    RETURN_FALSE;
}

mysqlnd_fetch_all(result, mode, return_value);
```

}

My guess would be I need to do something like

```
 PHP_FUNCTION(mysqli_current_row_num)
{
MYSQL_RES   *result;
zval        *mysql_result;


if (zend_parse_method_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), getThis(), "O|l", &mysql_result, mysqli_result_class_entry, &mode) == FAILURE) {
    return;
}
//this loads the result into my local result variable as a reference??
MYSQLI_FETCH_RESOURCE(result, MYSQL_RES *, mysql_result, "mysqli_result", MYSQLI_STATUS_VALID);

/*Now what : do I need to use the get_iterator like this..*/
return result->get_iterator()->row_num;

 /* do I need to use the entire iterator method name*/
  return result->php_mysqli_result_iterator_row_num();

}
```

Comment: Add a counter to the while

Comment: In complex rewinding and fast forwarding, I'd rather not have to constantly keep track of my own counter.

Comment: You did not mention _complex rewinding and fast forwarding,_

Answer (score 0):

Fast soloution:

```
$counter = 0;

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $counter++;
    // DO STUFF for actual $counter (offset);
}
```

Comment: it seems like people who have needed this before have written class extensions to make sure the counter is always incremented with mysqli_result->fetch_* calls...but the result set has an internal pointer, so why doesn't php expose it?

Comment: @user2782001 Because in 20 years I have never actually needed to know where I was in a resultset. Can you describe your requirement, why do you need to know which row you are processing and why do you need to jump about within the resultset